# Webview - how to detect if an url is invalid in Blackberry Cascades

Tags: c++, qt, webview, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

I am trying to find a way to detect whether an url is an invalid url for a webview

For example, if I do

myWebView->setUrl(QUrl("http://www.youtube.com")); //then the webview will change to that page, but if I do...

myWebView->setUrl(QUrl("youtube.com")); //it will not change, because it considers it an invalid url.

Is there some kind of signal, or some sort of property that I can use to detect that?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you have solution for this:

You can use inbuilt function `isValid();`

For eg :

```
myWwebView->url().isValid(); //It will return true or false value.
```

For more help refer following [link](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qurl.html#isValid)

Comment: Thankyou, but unfortunately this does not work.  My example of "youtube.com" that does not load a website still passes the url().isValid test - eventhough it takes "http://www.youtube.com" to load the page.  I guess what I am really asking for is a test to see if the webpage has loaded successfully or not or is able to load successfully.  I see there is a QWebView, that has a signal loadFinished(bool ok), where ok tells you if the load is successful, but I am using Blackberry Cascades Webview and QML.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect to the WebView's [loadingChanged](https://developer.blackberry.com/cascades/reference/bb__cascades__webview.html#loadingchanged) signal to find out if a page loaded successfully or not.